# Trouble to understand Agda's Coinduction

Tags: agda, coinduction

I'm trying to code a functional semantics for IMP language with parallel preemptive scheduling as presented in section 4 of the following [paper](http://cs.ioc.ee/~tarmo/papers/places13.pdf).

I'm using Agda 2.5.2 and Standard library 0.13. Also, the whole code is available at the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/rodrigogribeiro/dec9abb4c52423e2cecc732f4b4b5831).

First of all, I've defined the syntax of the language in question as inductive types.

```
  data Exp (n : ℕ) : Set where
    $_  : ℕ → Exp n
    Var : Fin n → Exp n
    _⊕_ : Exp n → Exp n → Exp n

  data Stmt (n : ℕ) : Set where
    skip : Stmt n
    _≔_ : Fin n → Exp n → Stmt n
    _▷_ : Stmt n → Stmt n → Stmt n
    iif_then_else_ : Exp n → Stmt n → Stmt n → Stmt n
    while_do_ : Exp n → Stmt n → Stmt n
    _∥_ : Stmt n → Stmt n → Stmt n
    atomic : Stmt n → Stmt n
    await_do_ : Exp n → Stmt n → Stmt n
```

The state is just a vector of natural numbers and expression semantics is straightforward.

```
  σ_ : ℕ → Set
  σ n = Vec ℕ n

  ⟦_,_⟧ : ∀ {n} → Exp n → σ n → ℕ
  ⟦ $ n , s ⟧ = n
  ⟦ Var v , s ⟧ = lookup v s
  ⟦ e ⊕ e' , s ⟧ = ⟦ e , s ⟧ + ⟦ e' , s ⟧
```

Then, I defined the type of resumptions, which are some sort of delayed computations.

```
  data Res (n : ℕ) : Set where
    ret : (st : σ n) → Res n
    δ   : (r : ∞ (Res n)) → Res n
    _∨_ : (l r : ∞ (Res n)) → Res n
    yield : (s : Stmt n)(st : σ n) → Res n
```

Next, following [1](http://cs.ioc.ee/~tarmo/papers/places13.pdf), I define sequential and parallel execution of statements

```
  evalSeq : ∀ {n} → Stmt n → Res n → Res n
  evalSeq s (ret st) = yield s st
  evalSeq s (δ r) = δ (♯ (evalSeq s (♭ r)))
  evalSeq s (l ∨ r) = ♯ evalSeq s (♭ l) ∨  ♯ evalSeq s (♭ r)
  evalSeq s (yield s' st) = yield (s ▷ s') st

  evalParL : ∀ {n} → Stmt n → Res n → Res n
  evalParL s (ret st) = yield s st
  evalParL s (δ r) = δ (♯ evalParL s (♭ r))
  evalParL s (l ∨ r) = ♯ evalParL s (♭ l) ∨ ♯ evalParL s (♭ r)
  evalParL s (yield s' st) = yield (s ∥ s') st

  evalParR : ∀ {n} → Stmt n → Res n → Res n
  evalParR s (ret st) = yield s st
  evalParR s (δ r) = δ (♯ evalParR s (♭ r))
  evalParR s (l ∨ r) = ♯ evalParR s (♭ l) ∨ ♯ evalParR s (♭ r)
  evalParR s (yield s' st) = yield (s' ∥ s) st
```

So far, so good. Next, I need to define statement evaluation function mutually with a operation to close (execute suspended computations) in a resumption.

```
  mutual
    close : ∀ {n} → Res n → Res n
    close (ret st) = ret st
    close (δ r) = δ (♯ close (♭ r))
    close (l ∨ r) = ♯ close (♭ l) ∨ ♯ close (♭ r)
    close (yield s st) = δ (♯ eval s st)

    eval : ∀ {n} → Stmt n → σ n → Res n
    eval skip st = ret st
    eval (x ≔ e) st = δ (♯ (ret (st [ x ]≔ ⟦ e , st ⟧ )))
    eval (s ▷ s') st = evalSeq s (eval s' st)
    eval (iif e then s else s') st with ⟦ e , st ⟧
    ...| zero = δ (♯ yield s' st)
    ...| suc n = δ (♯ yield s st)
    eval (while e do s) st with ⟦ e , st ⟧
    ...| zero = δ (♯ ret st)
    ...| suc n = δ (♯ yield (s ▷ while e do s) st )
    eval (s ∥ s') st = (♯ evalParR s' (eval s st)) ∨ (♯ evalParL s (eval s' st))
    eval (atomic s) st = {!!} -- δ (♯ close (eval s st))
    eval (await e do s) st = {!!}
```

Agda's totality checker complains when I try to fill the hole in `eval` equation for `atomic` constructor with `δ (♯ close (eval s st))` saying that termination checking fails for several points in both `eval` and `close` function.

My questions about this problem are:

1) Why is Agda termination checking complaining about these definitions? It appears to me that the call `δ (♯ close (eval s st))` is fine since it is done 
on a structurally smaller statement.

2) [Current Agda's language documentation](http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/coinduction.html) says that this kind musical notation based coinduction is the "old-way" coinduction in Agda. It recommends the use of 
coinductive records and copatterns. I've looked around but I'd not able to find examples of copatterns beyond streams and the delay monad. My question: is it possible to represent resumptions using coinductive records and copatterns?

Comment: wrt 1: while eval in `δ (♯ close (eval s st))` is called with a structurally smaller argument, close also calls eval on the result, with arguments of unknown size. So termination of eval can not be proved using induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to convince Agda that this terminates is to use sized types. That way you can show that `close x` is at least as well-defined as `x`.

First of all, here is a definition of `Res` based on coinductive records and sized types:

```
mutual
  record Res (n : ℕ) {sz : Size} : Set where
    coinductive
    field resume : ∀ {sz' : Size< sz} → ResCase n {sz'}
  data ResCase (n : ℕ) {sz : Size} : Set where
    ret : (st : σ n) → ResCase n
    δ   : (r : Res n {sz}) → ResCase n
    _∨_ : (l r : Res n {sz}) → ResCase n
    yield : (s : Stmt n) (st : σ n) → ResCase n
open Res
```

Then you can prove that `evalSeq` and friends preserve size:

```
evalStmt : ∀ {n sz} → (Stmt n → Stmt n → Stmt n) → Stmt n → Res n {sz} → Res n {sz}
resume (evalStmt _⊗_ s res) with resume res
resume (evalStmt _⊗_ s _) | ret st = yield s st
resume (evalStmt _⊗_ s _) | δ x = δ (evalStmt _⊗_ s x)
resume (evalStmt _⊗_ s _) | l ∨ r = evalStmt _⊗_ s l ∨ evalStmt _⊗_ s r
resume (evalStmt _⊗_ s _) | yield s' st = yield (s ⊗ s') st

evalSeq : ∀ {n sz} → Stmt n → Res n {sz} → Res n {sz}
evalSeq = evalStmt (\s s' → s ▷ s')

evalParL : ∀ {n sz} → Stmt n → Res n {sz} → Res n {sz}
evalParL = evalStmt (\s s' → s ∥ s')

evalParR : ∀ {n sz} → Stmt n → Res n {sz} → Res n {sz}
evalParR = evalStmt (\s s' → s' ∥ s)
```

And similarly for `close`:

```
mutual
  close : ∀ {n sz} → Res n {sz} → Res n {sz}
  resume (close res) with resume res
  ... | ret st = ret st
  ... | δ r = δ (close r)
  ... | l ∨ r = close l ∨ close r
  ... | yield s st = δ (eval s st)
```

And `eval` is as well-defined up to any size:

```
  eval : ∀ {n sz} → Stmt n → σ n → Res n {sz}
  resume (eval skip st) = ret st
  resume (eval (x ≔ e) st) = ret (st [ x ]≔ ⟦ e , st ⟧ )
  resume (eval (s ▷ s') st) = resume (evalSeq s (eval s' st))
  resume (eval (iif e then s else s') st) with ⟦ e , st ⟧
  ...| zero = yield s' st
  ...| suc n = yield s st
  resume (eval (while e do s) st) with ⟦ e , st ⟧
  ...| zero = ret st
  ...| suc n = yield (s ▷ while e do s) st
  resume (eval (s ∥ s') st) = evalParR s' (eval s st) ∨ evalParL s (eval s' st)
  resume (eval (atomic s) st) = resume (close (eval s st)) -- or δ
  resume (eval (await e do s) st) = {!!}
```